# Android open AlertDialog from another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have read conflicting reports on here and other sites that say it is/is not possible to show an alert dialog from another activity. What I'm trying to do it this:

```
public class Options extends Activity {

    /** Include classes */
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    Preferences prefs;
    Location loc;
    LocationSQL locSQL;
    NetworkConnection netConnect;

    /** Declare buttons */
    Button bLocation;
    Button bRefresh;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.options);

        sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Options.this);

        /** Set the location for the user */
        setLocationPref();

        /** Refresh selection */
        bRefresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRefresh);
        bRefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
        loc = new Location(getApplicationContext());
            try{

                loc.locationSelection();
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("ERROR", "Catch " + e);
            }
            }
        });

        /** Location selection */
        bLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLocation);
        bLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

I then want to do some processing and if needs be call a AlertDialog box. But I get the error below. I understand that I'm using a context that has been destroyed if I'm correct? But I can't think how to solve this?

```
public class Location {

    private static final String Context = null;
    NetworkConnection nc;
    SharedPreferences getSharedPrefs;
    SharedPreferences putSharedPrefs;
    NetworkConnection netConnect;
    Options opts;
    Context context;

    public Location (Context arg)
    {
        context = arg;
    }

    public void locationSelection(){

        message();

    }

    public void message(){

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Your Title");
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }

}
```

Catch android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application.

Many thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing getApplicationContext() to your Location constructor try passing YourClass.this (so here, Options.this).

Also, what is this line of code?

```
private static final String Context = null;
```

Comment: thanks yea that seems to have helped, thought I had tried that :/ that line of code was a copy and paste error, it shouldn't have been there, thanks for the help!